# Does resonance destabilize a molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]
According to this table, more heat is released in breaking a single double bond in 1,3-butadiene than in trans-2-butene. Does this mean that the resonance of 1,3 butadiene leads to a destabilization of the compound?

Comment: Your comparison is not correct. You are comparing two molecules with difference in internal bonding. You will not get trans-2-butene by removing 1 double bond from 1,3-butadiene. You should have compared 1-butene and 1,3-butadiene. Theoretically, addition of one double bond to 1-butene should give 1,3-butadiene, i.e. $\Delta H^0_{theo} = -60.6 $ kcal/mol. But practically it is lesser ($-57 $ kcal/mol) due to its higher stability due to conjugation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the comparisons you might make suggests any sort of deatabilization by conjugation.

Let's look at the four-carbon compounds.  Depending on which source you believe for 1,3-butadiene, you could release up to 27.8 kcal/mol by hydrogenating one double bond (the figures given for this compound refer to hydrogenating *both* double bonds).  But then you release 30.3 kcal/mol hydrogenating the remaining double bond in 1-butene.  The combination of two double bonds in 1,3-butadiene has less energy to be released by hydrogenation than two independent bonds like the bond in 1-butene has.

Similarly for the five-carbon compounds.  When you hydrogenated both double bonds in the pentadiene isomers, a pair of conjugated double bonds in 1,3-cyclopentadiene has less energy to release than the non-conjugated double bonds in 1,4-cyclopentadiene.

Finally, something a little more subtle is going on between 1-butene and 2-butene.  There can no conjugation like that in 1,3-butadiene when only one double bond is present, yet 2-butene has clearly less energy to release by hydrogenation than 1-butene.  Thinking of carbocation nomenclature, the former is a like a "secondary carbication by having an alkyl group on only one end of the double bonds, while the latter is "tertiary" with an alkyl group on both ends.  *Hyperconjugation*, like that in carbocations, is at work here.